# Remove CSS attribute when under certain resolution

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, resize

I have a few sections and the most popular one stands out

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
<div class="plan popular">
              <div class="price">
                <span class="amount" data-dollar-amount="79">Expert</span><br>
                <span class="dollar">$</span>
                <span class="amount" data-dollar-amount="79">79</span>
                <span class="slash">/</span>
                <span class="month">mo</span>
              </div>
                <p class="pop-plan">Most Popular Plan</p>
             <span>Track <b><font color="#13BD9B">1000</font></b> Keywords</span><br><br>
                <span>Get Mobile Rankings</span><br><br>
               <span>SEO Competitors</span><br><br>

                <span>Daily Updates</span><br><br>

              <span>Task Management
</span><br><br>
              <span>Unlimited Sites
</span><br><br>Unlimited Users
 <a class="button sign-up" href="https://orders.gigenetcloud.com/order.php?quick=79,40,2048,730">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
```

Here is the code for a section. The green one is simply part of the class named "popular". If I delete that part and let the div be of class "plan" then it is normal, with black like the rest.
I want to make it responsive, so when the resolution is low and only one section/line is shown, the green one loses the "plan" class and turns to normal to avoid bloating on smaller devices.

Right now it would look like this when resizing

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

thank you

Comment: I think you need to define style for `@media screen and (max-width < 768px) { .popular {...}}` and replace ellipsis with all attributes from class `.plan`

Comment: for manupulating just classes on html use a plugin response.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your style for `.popular` in a media query. like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .popular {
        border:2px solid green;
        /*rest of the styles*/
    }
}
```

This way your `popular` class will only be applied if the screen size is more than 768px.

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries to accomplish this. You can read more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

You would need to determine at what resolution you would want. Then set you css for what you want.