# Adding elements for certain resolutions

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

I found I can be unclear in these kind of questions, so I'll try my best explaining it in two formats:

1)
Currently I'm working on the responsiveness of my website and the usability of it.
Since my menu looks good on pc's, but not on mobile devices, I want to make use of a navigation bar, only visible on smartphones.
I found some help on W3Schools, but it won't let me have separate menu's for different resolutions.
How can I add a div on my html page, that isn't visible on pc screens or tablets, yet is visible on phones?

2)
This is what I'm looking for:
I'd like to have 2 menu's, one for pc/laptop or tablet screens only and the other only for smartphones.
I'd liketo use a navigation bar on the menu for smartphones (using a hamburger menu).
If I use the class for the nav-bar on the homepage, it shows it on every format, while if I use
display: none;
It won't show anywhere. How do I fix this?

I have searched for this question on stackoverflow (and other sites) and found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677077/remove-css-attribute-when-under-certain-resolution), though the solution in there hasn't worked for me so far. If the answers in there are actually fullfilling my question asked here, what am I doing wrong?

[Current code](http://jsfiddle.net/v2oqps5m/2/):

html:

```
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Logo</a>
  <div id="myLinks">
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
/*I won't put all css in here, as it would get a bit messy*/
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.topnav {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 768px){
.topnav {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
position: relative;
}

.topnav #myLinks {
display: none;
}

.topnav a {
color: white;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
display: block;
}

.topnav a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black;
}

.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For setting media queries, you use

```
@media (//media size in here) { 
  // css for that media query in here
}
```

A real example of this, is, for instance

```
@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

A basic burger-menu can be achieved by doing the following steps:

1) Create a with the class of burger-menu as a previous sibling element of the navigation you want to hide on mobile screen width.
a) You dont want this to show on your desktop medias, so in the css, style it as display: none;

2) Create a media query for the desired device. Let's say 480px for a mobile device.

3) Within this media query, style the navigation that you want to appear on hover (or click) as display: none;

4) Within this media query, style your burger-menu. In my example, I've styled something very basic, for time reasons, but you can research using spans to make a responsive burger menu.

5) Within this media query, declare an on hover pseudo-class for your burger-menu which accesses the hidden navigation. Since you placed the burger-menu as a the previous sibling element of your navigation, you can use the + css rule to target it like so

```
.burger-menu:hover + .menu {

}
```

This means that, when you hover over the burger-menu, you will affect the css of .menu. You can place how .menu's styles will be affected in the above CSS selector.

Here is a basic example of how this process works with your code.

Add this to your html, before your .menu

```
<div class="menu">
```

Add this to your css file, at the bottom

```
.burger-menu {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .burger-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
  }
  .burger-menu:hover + .menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Typically, you would advance this by using toggleClass with JQuery to add and remove display to your navigation menu on clicking the burger menu.

P.s the benefit of using spans to create your burger-menu will be when you want it to have nice animation, changing from a burger menu to a cross, or arrow, etc.

Answer (score 1):

(sorry for my bad English, also I know this reply is a little late but I hope it helps) You could have one CSS file meant for PC (in my example called pc.css) that hides the menu meant for mobile with `display: none;` and another that does the same thing but instead hides the one meant for PC (in my example called mobile.css). This can be accomplished with the following JS that checks if your screen width is less then or equal to 699px and then changes the CSS file pc.css to mobile.css

```
if (screen.width <= 699) {
    // get all links in the head (including CSS)
    var allLinks = document.head.getElementsByTagName('link');
    // find and replace the element
    for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
        if (allLinks[i].href = "pc.css") {
            allLinks[i].href = "mobile.css";
        }
```